# Setting "Max Score" in Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

Do the web services allow a user to update the Max Score value from an assignment? So for example, I upload a session where my Max Score is 15 and I want to upload the same assignment for the same class with a different score of 12. If so which call needs to be made to update the score?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [update grade object](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#put--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-grades-%28D2LID-gradeObjectId%29) and set the max score value inside the [GradeObject Resource](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#Grade.GradeObject).