# Desire2Learn Grades API, Max Score of 0

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a web service that allows a user to upload a session with a Max Score value of 0? Does a service handle that? If so, what is needed for a Max Score of 0 to appear in the grade item list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting "Max Score" in Desire2Learn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354965/setting-max-score-in-desire2learn)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, both in the web user interface, and through the APIs, you cannot create a grade object with an explicit MaxPoints property of 0: it seems that the minimum value is 0.01.